# django - different inlines for different users

Tags: django, inline

I have these models

```
class Office(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    status = models.SmallIntegerField()
    office = models.ForeignKey(Office, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

class Inspection(models.Model):
    place = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

class Jobs(models.Model):
    inspection = models.ForeignKey(Inspection, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    inspector = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
```

I have different users: common users(`status=1`) and admins(`status=2`).

Common users can make and see `Jobs` only with `Inspectors` from the same office.

Admins can put any user into `Inspectors` and see all `Jobs`.

I can filter job list for users in the same office:

```
class JobAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Job
    extra = 0
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(JobAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.status in [1]:
            qs = qs.filter(inspector__office=request.user.office)
        return qs

 class InspectionAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['place']
    inlines = [JobAdmin]
```

But how can I add additional filters for editing?

If it was not an inline form I would do it this way:

```
class JobAdminForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(JobAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.user.status == 1: #common user
            self.fields['inspector'].queryset = Inspector.objects.filter(office=self.user.office)

    class Meta:
        model = Jobs
        fields = '__all__'


class JobAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    form = JobAdminForm

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(JobAdmin, self).get_form(request, **kwargs)
        form.user = request.user
        return form
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this code will be helpfull:

```
class JobAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Job
    extra = 0

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(JobAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.status in [1]:
            qs = qs.filter(inspector__office=request.user.office)
        return qs

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "inspector" and request.user.status == 1:
            kwargs['queryset'] = Inspector.objects.filter(office=request.user.office)
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

P.S. Link to Django documentation: [formfield_for_foreignkey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey)

Comment: @MaslovAndrey In this case, can you mark my answer as a solution?